# In text analysis, what does the *density of coefficients* of a classifier model mean?

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, nlp, classification

I'm reading through [this very good text classifier example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/plot_document_classification_20newsgroups.html) from sklearn that takes a collection of documents (newspaper articles), vectorises the corpus, then runs the resulting `n x p` matrix through a series of classifiers and grabs some comparison metrics including the following code:

```
clf = SomeClassifier(parameters)
if hasattr(clf, 'coef_'):
    print(f"dimensionality: {clf.coef_.shape[1]}")
    print(f"density: {density(clf.coef_)}")
```

I know that the n x p sparse matrix has `n` rows (number of newspaper articles) and `p` predictor columns (number of tokens passed by the vectoriser, in my case individual words). I know that the attribute `coef_` only exists for models that form some kind of line or boundary, and that it has shape `c x p` where `c` is the number of classes from the target variable and uses the same `p` number of parameters passed to it by the vectoriser, which is `clf.coef_.shape[1]` in the example code. Unfortunately my matrix maths is very rusty, and I'm still learning NLP text analysis so I'm stuck with this last bit

Questions:

##### i) What does the function `density()` tell us about a matrix?

The example models  ~0.001-1.0 for the various model, so I assume this is something about the proportion of null/0 values in the array? I can't seem to find what library this function is even coming from, and my web searches keep returning density graphs or physics articles, which I don't think are relevant.

##### ii) What does the density of a `class c x p token predictor` matrix tell us about the text classifiers?

If density is the proportion of null values, I assume this tells us if the model is selecting relevant parameters on a class by class basis, like in LASSO / L1 normalisation. If this is the case, I assume that a very low value (density = ~0.001) means that most of the parameters are dropped, and a value of 1 means that the model is using every parameter to predict every class. Am I off the beaten track here? If I'm right, can anyone link to any articles or write examples to help me understand this?